# Запятая и тире после уточнения - не слишком ли "тяжёлый" знак?

Tags: пунктуация

> Смысла в такой трапезе, да на итальянской земле(,) – нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы: тире здесь излишне, ничем не мотивировано.

Answer (score 1):

Если уж любите тире - так поставьте два, вместо запятых, выделяя уточнение:

**Смысла в такой трапезе – да на итальянской земле – нет.**

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, коли уж так вопрос встал, здесь "да на итальянской земле" - уточнение, подлежащее обособлению, а "нет" в него не входит. После запятой ставить интонационное тире обычно нет смысла, запятая сама по себе дает основания сделать некоторую паузу.